# Android/Java: memory increases for 2 hours, then stabilizes. Is it normal behaviour?

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

My app has a few services running in the background and a simple GUI.

I just let it run for 3 hours to **detect memory leaks** and detected the following **behaviour**:

1. Memory **starts** with **28,8 MB**
2. Increases up to **44,3 MB after 2 hours**
3. Keeps **stable at around 44 MB**
4. **LeakCanary** didn't detect a leak

I'm wondering what's going on? Does the **Garbage Collector** wait until ~ 44 MB before it starts to clear?

The app itself was doing the **same thing for 3 hours**, in regular intervals. No memory consuming service was stopped.

Any idea or advices?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The memory is available, the application runs, the analysis tool did not spot any leak, what’s the problem?

Comment: @Holger I'm wondering why it took 2 hours until the it stopped increasing and would like to understand what's happening. Do you think it's the DC that allows the ~44 MB before cleaning up?

Comment: Would you be happier when it consumed 44MB right from the start?

Comment: @Holger No, and thanks for the question. I didn't see it that way. I just don't like that I don't know why it works. :-)

Comment: I appreciate curiosity, but there are lots of different factors affecting the memory management behavior, so to analyze it, a lot more information would be needed and you might need to invest a significant amount of time that is not worth it when there’s no actual problem to solve.

Comment: Thanks, @Holger, I'll get deeper into that topic once I face real issues. If you summarize your comments as an answer, the way stack overflow wants it, I will accept it. Thanks again!